# JPQL left outer join does unnecessary joins

Tags: jpa, left-join, jpql

I've got the following JPQL :

```
SELECT a.b.id, a.b.name, a.c.id,a.c.name 
 left join a.b left join a.c
 group by a.b.id,a.b.name,a.c.id,a.c.name
```

now b and c are both referencing the same table.
the generated SQL is doing the left join I asked, and another join for a.b.name and a.c.name
(which is unnecessary because the left join includes the name, and it retrieves more results than expected)
how do I make the SQL generated not include the unnecessary join?

1 solution came up is not select the names and retrieve them individually by a different query.. but it's not the most elegant way I suppose..

(btw I tried selecting a.b,a.c and group by a.b,a.c but it throws ORA not a group by expression because the generated sql retrieves all rows but group by is only by ID)
and the left join is necessary since I want to allow null values.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.b.id, a.b.name, a.c.id,a.c.name
```

The above implicitly creates an inner join between a abd b,a nd another inner join between a and c. The query should be

```
select b.id, b.name, c.id, c.name
from A a
left join a.b b
left join a.c c
```

The `group by` clause doesn't make any sense, since you have no aggregate in your select clause. `group by` would be useful if you had, for example

```
select b.id, b.name, c.id, c.name, count(c.foo)
from A a
left join a.b b
left join a.c c
group by b.id, b.name, c.id, c.name
```

Comment: yeah i have a count(a) which I didn't mention since it didnt really have anything to do with my problem. anyhow, it seems really helpful, thanks alot.